# Check the XCURSOR mouse animation before generate them

Tags: cursor, cursor-theme

I'm working on customizing [dmz-cursor-theme](https://github.com/ganwell/dmz-cursors) and i made an animated watch image , so Is there any method to check mouse cursor animation before generated them ?